# RabbitMq Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 Failed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm currently following a rabbitmq tutorial and running into an issue. No matter how close I follow the tutorial I keep getting this error when trying to run my send.py and receive.py:

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 failed: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

This is the send.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

This is the receive.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at other post on here that ask a similar question but still no dice.

Comment: Have you checked status of server with `/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server status`

Comment: Do you have RabbitMQ Server installed and running on your desktop?

Answer (score 4):

I used the same tutorial it seems, and they did miss the dependency to install and run rabbitmq

After doing `brew install rabbitmq` and then `brew services start rabbitmq` the connection to localhost on Pika then works

Answer (score 3):

If you are using docker to run rabbitmq and followed instructions in the tutorial and the docker page (https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/rabbitmq), you might run into this problem.  When you run the container without specifying the port mapping option ("-p"), the port binding will be valid only within the container. You can verify by doing a "docker exec" into the container and then running netstat.
So what you would want to do is to restart the rabbitmq container and specify a port mapping. Example:
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:latest

Comment: I don't know why this didn't get marked up before- worked for me! I deleted my "some-rabbit" container, executed this command, and changes the port in my python code 5672. Bingo!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using docker to run your rabbitmq? If yes, I suggest you to double check ports binding. For example: -p 5672:5672

Comment: The tutorial I'm using didn't mention anything about using docker.

Comment: So I don't know. I had the same issue when I using docker to run rabbit locally: https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/

Comment: Yeah, I seems that this is a pretty elusive issue. For me at least.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps fixed it for me:

1. In your Terminal, run `brew info rabbitmq`. It should show if all dependencies are installed (install any that is missing):

2. Make sure you have your ***.zshrc*** file in your usr directory. If you don't have it, then run `touch ~/.zshrc` in a terminal.
3. In your .zshrc file, make sure you have either of these two lines:

   (Mac Intel)`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`

   (MAC Silicon)`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/sbin`
4. Finally, in your Terminal run `brew services restart rabbitmq` and test again